# What databases could run the following SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have constructed a query and I'm wondering if it would work on any database besides MySQL. I have never actually used another database so I'm not great with the differences.

```
UPDATE `locks` AS `l1`
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(`value`) AS `sum` FROM `locks`
              WHERE `key` IN ("key3","key2")) AS `l2`
SET `l1`.`value` = `l1`.`value` + 1
WHERE `l1`.`key` = "key1" AND (`l2`.`sum` < 1);
```

Here are the specific features I'm relying on (as I can think of them):

1. <strike>Update queries.</strike>
2. Joins in update queries.
3. Aggregate functions in non-explicitly-grouped queries.
4. WHERE...IN condition.

I'm sure people will be curious exactly what this does, and this may also include database features that might not be ubiquitous. This is an implementation of mutual exclusion using a database, intended for a web application. In my case I needed it because certain user actions cause tables to be dropped and recreated with different columns, and I want to avoid errors if other parts of the application try to insert data. The implementation, therefore, is specialized to solve [the readers-writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem).

This query assumes there exists a table `locks` with two fields: `key` (varchar) and `value` (int). It further assumes that the table contains a row such that `key`="key1". Then it tries to increment the `value` for "key1". It only does so if for every `key` in the list `("key2","key3")`, the associated `value` is 0 (the WHERE condition for `l2` is an approximation that assumes `value` is never negative). Therefore this query only "obtains a lock" if certain conditions are met, presumably in an atomic fashion. Then, the application checks if it received a lock by the return value of the query which presumably states how many rows were affected. If and only if no rows were affected, the application did not receive a lock.

So, here are the additional conditions not discernable from the query itself:

1. Assumes that in a multi-threaded environment, a copy of this query will never be interleaved with another copy.
2. Processing the query must return whether any values were affected.

As a secondary request, I would appreciate any resources on "standard SQL." I've heard about it but never been able to find any kind of definition, and I feel like I'm missing a lot of things when the MySQL documentation says "this feature is an extension of standard SQL."

Based on the responses, this query should work better across all systems:

```
UPDATE locks AS l1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(val) AS others FROM locks
              WHERE keyname IN ('key3','key2')) AS l2
SET l1.val = l1.val + 1
WHERE l1.keyname = 'key1' AND (l2.others < 1);
```

Upvotes for everyone because of the good answers. The marked answer seeks to directly answer my question, even if just for one other DBMS, and even though there may be better solutions to my particular problem (or even the problem of cross-platform SQL in general).

Comment: The reader-writers problem is only an "issue" in databases when transactions are not implemented or used [correctly]. InnoDB is much more of a "real" RDBMS than MyISAM for this very reason.... is the use of the [dining philosopher problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) just for a theoretical example or assignment?

Comment: It's not a specific use of the dining philosopher problem and it's a solution to a real world problem. I am studying concurrency right now, not databases, so it's possible this feature is in fact built into SQL. I've heard of transactions but never known much about them; I think this may be the proper solution to my problem even though it's not an answer to my question.

Comment: On second thought, having looked into transactions, I don't think it will work for my application in MySQL because the concurrency problem I'm trying to avoid is access to a table that's being dropped and recreated, with another table being updated to describe the information. Because MySQL does not really support table altering during transactions, I'm not clear that the entire transaction would be atomic. I looked into MySQL `LOCK TABLES` too but they don't allow `CREATE TABLE` queries when a lock is held.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For PostgreSQL

> 1) Update queries.

Can't imagine a RDBMS that has no `UPDATE`. (?)

> 2) Joins in update queries.

In PostgreSQL you would include additional tables with [`FROM from_list`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html).

> 3) Aggregate functions in non-grouped queries.

Not possible in PostgreSQL. Use subqueries, CTE or Window functions for that.
But your query **is** grouped. The `GROUP BY` clause is just not spelled out. That works in PostgreSQL, too.

> The presence of HAVING turns a query into a grouped query even if
>   there is no GROUP BY clause. This is the same as what happens when the
>   query contains aggregate functions but no GROUP BY clause.

[(Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)).

> 4) WHERE...IN condition

Works in any RDBMS I know of.

> "Additional conditions": Assumes that in a multi-threaded environment, a copy of this query will never be interleaved with another copy.

PostgreSQL's [multiversion model MVCC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html) (Multiversion Concurrency Control) is superior to MySQL for handling concurrency. Then again, most RDBMS are superior to MySQL in this respect.

> Processing the query must return whether any values were affected.

Postgres does that, most every RDBMS does.

Furthermore, this query wouldn't run in PostgreSQL because:

- no [identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) with backticks (that's MySQL slang).
- values need to be single-quoted, not double-quoted.

See the [list of reserved words in Postgres and SQL standards](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).
A [combined list for various RDBMS](http://drupal.org/node/141051).

Comment: Also, I suspect that there will be a DBMS platform that refuses the column name 'sum', which is a reserved word (though a aggregate function name might live in a separate 'syntactic namespace')

Answer (score 6):

This exact syntax would only work in `MySQL`.

It's an ugly workaround for this construct:

```
UPDATE  locks
SET     value = 1
WHERE   key = 'key1'
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    locks li
        WHERE   li.key IN ('key2', 'key3')
                AND li.value > 0
        )
```

which works in all systems except `MySQL`, because the latter does not allow subqueries on the target table in `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements.

Comment: value = value + 1. (Though this might fulfill the purpose, too.) You are right otherwise.

Comment: It's good to know that other RDBMS allow a `SELECT` subquery in `UPDATE` queries for the same table. It's also simultaneously infuriating that MySQL doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 2):

This will only work in mysql, just because you use "`" delimiter, which is mysql-specific only.

What if you replace delimiter with more "standard" one: then probably it will work in all modern DBMS (postgres, sql server, oracle), but I would never write a general query for all - I'd better written a specific query for each used (or potentially used) DBMS to use its specific language dialects to get the best performance and query readability.

What about "As a secondary request, I would appreciate any resources on "standard SQL."" --- get a look at http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. What about the rest of it? Also, if I remove the "\`" delimiter, is there any other way to escape my field names to avoid stepping on any reserved keywords (like `key`)?

Comment: @meustrus The SQL standard specifies `"` for identifier quotes.

Comment: @zerkms: Are you sure that MySQL accepts `" "` delimiters for table and field names?

Comment: @ypercube: you would need to enable `ANSI_QUOTES` in `sql_mode` for this to work (which would break their usage in strings), but yes, it's possible.

Comment: It seems like the simplest solution is to just use single quotes for strings and not quote identifiers. Is there a list of reserved words for all DBMS that I can check against?

Comment: @meustrus: I added lists of reserved words to my answer.